# Display images with different extensions Yii2

Tags: php, image, yii2

Please, help me to display images with different extensions.

Here is my code to display

```
<?php
        foreach ($users as $arr) {
            $imageName = $arr->username;
            $extension = 'jpg';
        ?>
        <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-4">
            <div class="thumbnail">
                <?= Html::img('/uploads'.'/'.$imageName.'.'.$extension, ['class' => 'img-rounded', 'style' => 'width: 300px; height: 250px'])   ?>
```

This code displaying only 'jpg' images, and i need to display for e. 'jpg','png'.

Comment: you can store image name with extension, so no need of this kind of stuff.

Comment: +1 to Crazzy Skull's. You can also save the extension on a different field if you need the file name without it.

Answer (score 0):

or You can check file exists

```
$extensions = ['jpg','png','gif'];
foreach($extensions as $extension){
    if(file_exists(Yii::getAlias('@web').'path/to/uploads'.$imageName.'.'.$extension)) {
        echo Html::img('/uploads/'.$imageName.'.'.$extension, ['class' => 'img-rounded', 'style' => 'width: 300px; height: 250px']);
        break;
    }
}
```

but it's wrong way you should do this as Insane Skull said as

> you can store image name with extension, so no need of this kind of
>   stuff